# Convergence of $A_{n}x_{n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X, Y$ Banach space, $A_{n} \in \mathcal{L}(X, Y).$

Assume for all $x \in X$, $\,A_{n}x \to Ax\,$ and $\,x_{n} \to x$.

How to show that $A_{n}x_{n} \to Ax$.

My attempt was $\lVert A_n x_n - Ax\rVert \leqslant\lVert A_n x_n - A_n x\rVert +\lVert A_n x - Ax\rVert\;,\;$ but I don't understand what should I do next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A_nx$ converge for any $x$ then they have uniformly bounded norms, i.e. $\lVert A_n\rVert\leqslant M$ for any $n$. This has a name like "uniformly boundedness principle" or something. Or it can be proved using Baire's category lemma. Anyhow, with this in hand the term $\lVert A_nx_n-A_nx\rVert$ can be estimated by $M\lVert x_n-x\rVert$ so it tends to $0$. The second one goes to $0$ by assumption.